# Difference between deformable and flexible

Tags: synonyms

Part of my work is the following sentence:

> we limit the scope of this work to static, non-deformable and non-flexible objects.

However I wonder whether there is a difference between the words non-deformable and non-flexible. Or are they just unambiguous synonyms?

Comment: What field of knowledge are you dealing with? What have you found in the dictionary, and why didn't it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deformable means that the shape of something can be changed into something else.  For example, in [topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology), a coffee cup can be deformed into a torus.  Note the Wikipedia article refers to this deformation as a homeomorphism.  A torus cannot be deformed into a sphere, hence they are not homeomorphic.

Flexible means that a substance can be bent, for example an arm joint, or the handle on a briefcase.  It would not be correct to say that a briefcase handle is deformable or that a dancer is deformable.

Definitions for [deformable](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DeformableBody.html) and [flexible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flexible).

Comment: *Flexible* usually suggest the object can easily return to its original shape or position. Also, a briefcase handle made of plastic **is** deformable if you apply heat (and other materials might also be deformed). Similarly a dancer can be seriously injured and might be described as *deformed*, although the term would probably be considered insensitive.

Comment: Really?  So you want to talk about melting a briefcase handle as a counter argument?  In that case, everything is flexible and deformable if you apply fire, extreme force, or have it sucked into a black hole.

Comment: To some degree, yes. Usually *deformable* is modified, as in *easily deformable with hand pressure* or *deformable when gently heated*. I think the term would probably not be used to describe a complete change in state (solid to liquid) or substantial destruction (explosive force).

Comment: @Rathony I saw the duplicates you listed for the past perfect question.  In my opinion, I don't think the questions would have helped the OP.  Also, I did vote to close and move to ELL.  I think it would be valuable to open a general discussion on duplicates in Meta because I see many people tag questions as duplicates but the listed duplicates aren't really duplicates.  You would not be mentioned if I did open a meta on how to properly identify duplicates.

Comment: I didn't close it for duplicates and I didn't list them as duplicates. They are not duplicates. The question is too much basic for EL&U. That's all. I don't mind leaving my comment trails as I am not one of moderators' best friends. but I deleted them. Judging whether any question is a duplicate is one thing and judging whether a question has any research/context is another. ELL is there for that kind of question. Judging whether it belongs to ELU or ELL is as much critical as judging whether it is a duplicate.